# register your app to be shared photos with

Tags: android

I'm trying to search this but perhaps I don't have the right keywords, basically the question is how to register your app with android operating system to enable it for sharing photos.

Let's say you are in the gallery and you want to share a photo with this app, how this app can be classified as a sharing target and how do you handle data within the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent/) I believe that for images you need to add this code in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

In the activity that you want to open when the app is selected.